# Port number not changing in jenkins and it showing default port number only

Tags: jenkins

After changing the port number in 8080 to 9999 and it not changing in jenkins. And it showing the default port number 8080 only.

I restart the jenkins service with this command also

"service jenkins restart"
"systemctl jenkins restart"

but its not works, I worked on "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" server

## port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)

HTTP_PORT=9999

--httpPort=8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1401952/1586251
I answered the same question.

TLDR;

Refer to the documentations in: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

It says that you can modify by: `systemctl edit jenkins`

Then add the following lines:

> [Service] Environment="JENKINS_PORT=9999"

Port should be your desired port to use. Save it and then restart jenkins: `sudo systemctl restart jenkins`

Comment: I did , but no luck. it still runs on the same default port 8080.
I have edited the /etc/default/jenkins too, but no affect applied.